# How to choose drivers for forecasts based on vector autoregression

Tags: forecasting, feature-selection, vector-autoregression

as mentioned in the title my question is how to choose from a large set of time series the best Driver for a forecast based on vector autoregression. I am sure that this question is very general. I just need some references to deep dive in this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean by driver? What do you want to do, choose variables for your VAR?

Comment: yes, indeed. How to choos the variables to forecast my target variable in using VAR